# Does scala-3 macros support compile-time global variables? How to use them?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

A use case needs to compare the actual type of two type parameters at runtime time. That might be easily done with `TypeTag`, but it is deprecated in scala-3.
Therefore I tried with `TypeTest` but it requires the existence of an instance of the type, which I don't have.
So, I implemented `TypeId`, my own version of `TypeTag`. It is way way more limited and simple. It only supports type comparison and works only if a single instance of `TypeId` exists for each involved type.

```scala
import scala.collection.{mutable, immutable}

object TypeId {
    private var idSequencer: Int = 0

    private val typeIds: mutable.HashMap[Int, TypeId[?]] = mutable.HashMap.empty

    private def registerNew[A](tm: TypeId[A]): Int = this.synchronized {
        idSequencer += 1
        typeIds.put(idSequencer, tm)
        idSequencer
    }

    def knownTypeIds: immutable.HashMap[Int, TypeId[?]] = this.synchronized(immutable.HashMap.from(typeIds))
}

trait TypeId[A] {
    val id: Int = registerNew(this)
    def equalsTo(that: TypeId[?]): Boolean = this.id == that.id
}
```

As you can see, it requires synchronization to be thread-safe, which is not convenient; and the value of `knownTypeIds` is vulnerable to race conditions.

I wonder if it is possible to create the unique ids at compile using a macro. I suppose that to do that I need some kind of compile-time global variable to implement the sequencer. Does scala-3 macros support compile time global variables or an alternative to achieve my goal?

**EDIT:**
A couple of minutes after asking my question I came up with a very simple way to achieve my goal by making the identifier a string with the extended name of the type. Such a name can easily be generated in a macro.
However, I leave the question to know if scala-3 macros support compile-time global variables.

Here is the code that achieves my goal using the name of the type instead of sequential integer.

```scala
import scala.collection.{immutable}

object TypeId {

    @volatile
    private var typeIds: immutable.Set[String] = immutable.HashSet.empty

    def knownTypeIds: immutable.Set[String] = typeIds

    private inline def registerNew[A]: String = {
        val id = TypeIdMacros.createId[A]
        this.synchronized(typeIds += id)
        id
    }
}

trait TypeId[A] {
    val id: String = registerNew[A]

    def equalsTo(that: TypeId[?]): Boolean = this.id == that.id
}
```

```scala
import scala.quoted.{Quotes, Type, Expr}

object TypeIdMacros {

    inline def createId[A]: String = ${createIdImpl[A]}

    def createIdImpl[A](using typeA: Type[A], quotes: Quotes): Expr[String] =
        Expr(Type.show[A])
}
```

Comment: Your problem (TypeTag in Scala 3) is more or less the use case of izumi-reflect: https://github.com/zio/izumi-reflect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a very bad idea, because of incremental compilation - it's quite hard to tell exactly what will be compiled or when. You could easily get something that works on a `clean` compile, but fails on partial re-compiles during development as not every bit of code that should be triggering the sequencer gets fired.

(I'm not sure if it's doable at all, and there might be other reasons to avoid it, but this is a general reason to avoid any sort of imperative code in macros.)

Comment: Perhaps, if instead of global they (the compile-time variables) were local to some artifact that triggers re-compilation of all files that reference it when any of them is touched. Uhmm... too much language design effort for little value gain.